# Laravel Polymorphic Many to Many - Query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-query-builder

In my Project, i have Companies, Users, and Airplanes Models.

Users and Airplanes are companyable like so:

```
public function companies()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Company', 'companyable');
    }
```

Now, i'd like to return "All Airplanes" of "All Companys" the User is attached to.

I'm currently doing this via the User Model:

```
public function airplanes()
    {
        $myAirplanes = [];
        foreach ($this->companies AS $company) {
            $myAirplanes[] = $company->airplanes;
        }
        return $myAirplanes;
    }
```

But i'd like to do that with a single query. Does anyone know a way? Thank you very much for helping

Answer (score 0):

you should use eager load for this but you will need airplanes relationship on company. if you write it only need to eager load like this in controller:

```
User::find($id)->load('companies.airplanes');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is not exactly what i am looking for as it returns the User with companies and airplanes, but i want it to return airplanes only :/

Comment: So it becomes to this ```User::whereId($id)->companies()->first()->airplanes```